# context deadline extended - prometheus - while running on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I'm trying to get a spring microservice to regsiter on Prometheus. Both are running on docker. I get "context deadline exceeded" in the Prometheus UI for my service.

Funnily, when i try to open "localhost:8081/metrics" in a new tab, it shows the metrics.

This is my docker-compose.yml. This issue seems pretty common but I've not come across a solution that works for me ; yet.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
networks:
   cadrs:
     ipam:
       config:
          - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16

services:
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:0.18.0
    volumes:
        - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
        - '-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    ports:
        - '9090:9090'

demo:
    build: "C:/Users/hmt843/Downloads/demo"
    hostname: "demo"
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    networks:
       cadrs:
          ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2
node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:v0.15.0
    ports:
        - '9100:9100'
```

prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
        monitor: 'my-monitor'

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'prometheus'
      target_groups:
          - targets: ['localhost:9090']
    - job_name: 'demo'
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
      target_groups:
          - targets: ['172.28.1.2:8081']
    - job_name: 'node-exporter'
      target_groups:
          - targets: ['node-exporter:9100']
```

Comment: Does scraping the node_exporter works? And did you confirm that the IP of the "demo" container really is 172.28.1.2 ? Any reason you use the IP directly for that one and not "demo:8081" as the scrape target ?

Comment: Yes the node exporter works and the IP is really 172.28.1.2. 
demo:8081 does not work. Is there any other way I can run it through docker?

Comment: If I run it with "demo:8081" it displays this error: 
Get http://demo:8081/metrics: dial tcp 10.4.73.24:8081: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: Can you confirm that a) the demo app is up and running on port 8081 and listening on all interfaces (connect to the demo container and use netstat / curl) and b) that you can reach it from the prometheus container via curl/wget ?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the network section in your app‘s service the container is placed in a separate docker network called `cadrs`. Your Prometheus service has no such network definition and thus is in the `default` network. Containers must reside in at least one common network to be able to access each others. Even exposing the container on the host port doesn’t affect this (but you could reach the app via your host ip - don’t do this).

If you really need this network configuration, either add Prometheus to the same network by adding the same network section to your Prometheus service or introduce another network (e.g. `monitoring`) that is used in both services. Alternatively you could also specify that your app is in the default network by adding one more line to your networks section of the app.

```
networks:
  cadrs:
    [...]
  default:
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network

With this setup, you can modify your scrape configuration also back to `demo:8081`. Either way, ask yourself if you really want to use manage container addresses by yourself...